# How to store in an allocated space a value contained in a counter register converted in ASCII

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I have a `for` cycle that check the presence of a Char in a string, and store the index of it in aother, in this way:

Pseudocode:

```
for (x = 0; x < string.len(); x++) {
    if (string[x] == "A") {
        new_string.append(x)
    }
}
```

This is what I tried in MIPS

MIPS:

```
    add  $t0, $zero, $zero    # $t0 is the counter
loop:
    blt  $s2, $t0, Exit       # $s2 have the string.len()
    add  $s0, $s1, $t0        # point to the X char
                              # ($s1 is the string address)
    lb   $t1, 0($s0)
    bne  $t1, 0x41, endLoop   # if $t1 != "A" continue

    sb   $t0, 0($s4)          # store in newstring the X value
    addi $s4, $s4, 1          # point to the next space of newstring
endLoop:
    addi $t0, $t0, 1          # increment X
    j    loop
Exit:
```

In this mode I'll store the digit in the buffer, with `sb  $t0, 0($s4)`. I need to convert that value in the ASCII representation.

The length max of the input string can be of 256. So i need a representation that consider this limit.

I need the ASCII representation because the output string will be handled by other function, that crypt the input string, with the property of ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

When you increment the destination address you incorrectly use `$s3`. It should be `addi $s4, $s4, 1`

Also, `x <= string.len()` is the wrong ending condition. It should be `x < string.len()` since you start at 0.

Comment: @tum_ The branch is fine, except that it's off by one (it jumps to `Exit` when `string.len() < x`, i.e. when `x > string.len()`).

Comment: maybe I explained myself wrong.. my problem is not in the flow but in instruction `sb $t0, 0($s4)` which does not store in the buffer what is in the register `$t0` in the way that I want..

Comment: @Kenyskrachor: I have tested the code with my changes, and it works as I'd expect it to. You'll have to clarify exactly what you mean by not storing the way you want.

Comment: @Kenyskrachor: Are you using a debugger to inspect the memory? What is the initial value of $s4 (which you decided not to show)?

Comment: @Michael Sure, silly me, will kill the comment. And, yes, it's still off by one at the moment.

Comment: @tum_: yes I'm using QTSpim and when I inspect memory there's not the number in the relative address..

Comment: `QTSpim` means nothing to me but do you actually single-step through instructions  and check the memory after the `sb` is executed? Or do you check the memory at some point "afterwards"?

Comment: You're not expecting digits are you? Because `1` and `'1'` are different values.

Comment: I'm doing a step by step control. maybe the representation are not the same in memory? and what I see are not what I expected but it works?

Comment: @Michael: Ok maybe that's the point. There's a way to convert it?

Comment: For values less than 10 you can just add `'0'` before storing it. For larger values it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: ..or set $t0 to 0x30 ('0') from the start but then you need to adjust your exit condition and/or $s2 content. In any case, storing an index as ASCII is weird but that's your program so you are the boss. :)

Comment: @tum_: the reason why I have to use ASCII is because the buffer that containing the digits, will be written in to a file that will contain all the indexes.

Comment: Kenyskrachor: As I said - it's all up to you, none of us here knows what is the ultimate task that you're solving.   Non-ascii data can be written to a file just as well, so *this alone* does not really justifies your choice. What's the max string length that you plan to manage? As @Michael pointed out for you - if it exceeds 10, you might face a bit of a problem.

Comment: This code is one of four algorithms that handle and crypt a message. If I use the digit I'll lose the property of the ASCII. One of this algorithms that I'll use, for example, sum the value of 4 to every letter of the message. So.. Yes I need to use ASCII representation of the value stored in $t0.

Comment: The dimension are more than 10.. The original message have a limit of 256 letters. The output message have no limits

Comment: maybe the question is more complex than I put it

Comment: You can always [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55965610/edit) your own question if you feel the need for this. Few people bother reading and following multiple comments...

Comment: clear hope as reformulation .. my English is quite limited